# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax. Why?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run the following query but it is giving me this error:

```
Error
SQL query:

/* Then insert some posts for testing: */ INSERT INTO posts( title, body, created ) 
VALUES (

’The title’, ’This IS the post body.’, NOW( )
);

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'titleâ€™, â€™This is the post body.â€™, NOW())' at line 3
```

Here is the code,

```
 /* First, create our posts table: */
    CREATE TABLE posts (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(50),
    body TEXT,
    created DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    modified DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
    );

    /* Then insert some posts for testing: */
    INSERT INTO posts (title,body,created)
    VALUES (’The title’, ’This is the post body.’, NOW());
    INSERT INTO posts (title,body,created)
    VALUES (’A title once again’, ’And the post body follows.’, NOW());
    INSERT INTO posts (title,body,created)
    VALUES (’Title strikes back’, ’This is really exciting! Not.’, NOW());
```

Comment: you have backticks for values it should be single quote `''` `values ('the title',...)`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty make it an answer; Though `’` is the right single quote, Unicode U+2019. SQL probably was edited with Word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the proper apostrophes for your strings:

```
INSERT INTO posts( title, body, created ) 
VALUES (
'The title', 'This IS the post body.', NOW( )
);
```

You used `’` instead of `'`. I assume you edited the file using some wordprocessor (like Word, LibreOffice, etc.). Just use a plain old text editor (like Notepad, Vi, etc.).